# Does $x^3-x+3$ have any roots in $\mathbb{F}_5$?

Tags: splitting-field

Does $x^3-x+3$ have any roots in $\mathbb{F}_5$? I don't think it does but the only way I know to check is by trial and error and there's only so many factors I can try before my hand cramps up.

Comment: This is small enough you don’t even need to write anything. Just calculate the numbers in your head...

Comment: @Clayton One doesn't even need a calculation.  Use the ["cubing lemma"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706037/modular-arithmetic-roots-of-integers/2706045#2706045) with $p = 5$ and $k = 3$.  Then every number is a cube.

Comment: @GNUSupporter But this cube ($x^3)$ need not coincide with $x-3$

Comment: You don't have to check the factors with polynomial long division, you only have to insert the numbers $0,1,2,3,4$ and look whether the value of the polynomial is divisible by $5$

Comment: @Peter Sorry for my careless mistake.

Comment: @Peter Trying $0,1,2,3,4$ seems awfully difficult. Better to try $-2,-1,0,1,2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $$x^3-x=x\left(x^2-1\right) = (x-1) x (x+1)$$
hence $-1, 0, 1$ will not work as you need $x^3-x=-3 \equiv 2 \pmod 5$, check the other values $\pm 2$?